# Conditional Density Of Independent Bernoulli Random Variables Given Their Sum

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function, linear-algebra, bernoulli-distribution

Let Yi's be m independent Bernoulli random variables with corresponding success probabilities pi's, and let S = sum of Yi's.

I am trying to figure out a way to find the given conditional probability, **P(Y1 = y1,......Ym = ym|S = s) = ?**. I know how to work this out when these are identically distributed (i.e., all pi's are identical), but not sure about how to approach when pi's are distinct. Please help if you can.

PS: In the identically distributed case, S ~ Binomial (m,p), which makes it easy to compute the above probability.

Comment: Appt in a few minutes, so haven't checked this in detail. Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934941/conditional-probability-in-multinomial-distribution) helpful?

Comment: Thanks, BruceET. It is very slightly related to it, and I am not sure if that helps much. My question involves a sum of independent random variables, and the pi's need not have any condition imposed on them.